# How to audit database changes using slick

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I am using slick 3.2 as the DB access library in a project.
One of the requirements is to track all data changes. I am looking for something similar as Hibernate Envers module.

I was looking at [Active Slick](https://github.com/strongtyped/active-slick), any experiences with it?

If possible I would like to avoid going the full CQRS way.